# Cannot click listview items

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-listview

I have populate a listview with data from firebase. I want to able to click its items to open another activity, but I could figure out how,
here is what I tried
my adapter class

```
public class VideoClassAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<VideoClass> {
    public VideoClassAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<VideoClass> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.lesson_list_item, parent, false);
        }

        VideoClass videoClass = getItem(position);

        TextView lessonName, lessonNumber;

        lessonName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.lesson_name_text);
        lessonName.setText(videoClass.getTitle());

        lessonNumber = convertView.findViewById(R.id.lesson_number_text);
        lessonNumber.setText(videoClass.getLesson_number());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

how I populate the list view

```
arVideoArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new VideoClassAdapter(getContext(),R.layout.lesson_list_item, arVideoArrayList);

        mArRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                view.findViewById(R.id.arabic_progressBar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                arVideoArrayList.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()){
                    VideoClass videoClass = ds.getValue(VideoClass.class);
                    arVideoArrayList.add(videoClass);
                }
                arListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
```

And the listview on item click listener

```
arListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                VideoClass videoClass = arVideoArrayList.get(position);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "CLICKED" + videoClass.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

but no result at all.
**UPDATE** it worked after I removed add to favorites toggle button,
Anyone can help with an explanation?

Comment: Does the Toast of `"CLICKED"` is shown when you click an item?

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. Use `Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: @AlexMamo the thing the listview doesn't get clicked!. usually Even if I don't attach any click listener to a listview I still get the ripple effect when I touch its items, but with this one!